# multiple temporary udfs in same file

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to create multiple temporary UDFs in the same SQL Server .sql file such that the primary temporary procedure in the file can refer to those temporary UDFs, like a one procedure calling another in a program?

Comment: yes it is possible. Did you try it? What is the point of a temporary UDF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Temporary User Defined Functions (UDFs) or temporary stored procedures? Temp UDFs are not allowed.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.#whatever() RETURNS int AS BEGIN RETURN 1 END
```

> Creation of temporary functions is not allowed.

Multiple temporary stored procedures can be included in the same file, but must be defined in separate batches, just like normal procedures. `GO` on a line by itself is the normal batch separator.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE #one AS BEGIN
    SELECT 1 AS "one"
END
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE #two AS BEGIN
    EXEC dbo.#one
END
GO

EXEC dbo.#two
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, Shannon!